# PowerBI Union Vs SQL

Tags: sql, select, powerbi, union

I have two table's Table A (ID,Name,Location) and Table B(ID , Name)
When we do Union in SQL, Instead of adding any blank location column in TableB, we can perform Union like this

```
Select ID, name, Location from TableA
Union
Select ID, name, '' as Location from TableB
```

Here I am dynamically adding column in **select statement** I am **not adding blank column in table B** itself.

**Can we achieve the same in PowerBI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Append the tables in Power Query.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries